# Github syntax highlighting theme for SublimeText2?

Tags: github, sublimetext2, color-scheme

Is there a ST2 color theme that looks like the Github pygments color scheme?

Comment: How the f**k is this off topic? I hate this website sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GitHub TextMate theme](https://github.com/sbecker/github_textmate_theme) by sbecker (compatible with Sublime Text 2) is the closest match I could find.

[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3721)